# Replace в массиве

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть строковый массив данных, набранный при парсинге из xml.

```
doc=[]
```

Пытаюсь пройти по нему и удалить ненужные символы.

```
for i, el in enumerate(doc):
    el[i] = str(el).replace(',', '').replace(';', '')
    csvwriter.writerow(doc)
```

Но на выходе имею:

> el[i] = str(el).replace(',', '').replace(';', '')
>
> TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Не так - использование цикла `for`!  Выражение написано в ответе ibs, причем его надо прямо вставить внутрь `csvwriter.writerow()` даже без квадратных скобок.

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment` означает, что строки не поддерживают изменение через квадратные скобки (`item assignment`).

В python'е строки неизменяемый объект

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Как тогда правильно организовать проверку массива на наличие символа?

Comment: Мне кажется, что в вашем случае будет так: `el = el.replace(',', '').replace(';', '')`. Судя по ошибке в `el[i]`, у вас и так там строка, поэтому `str(el)` излишный. Да и обработка идет для текущей строки, поэтому индексация не нужна

Answer (score 0):

```
Допустим: doc = ['as,rt;de', 'aqw', ',df', 'fhg;']

d = [el.replace(',', '').replace(';', '') for el in doc]

print(d)      # ['asrtde', 'aqw', 'df', 'fhg']
```

Comment: Как вариант я записываю массив в новую строку, там делаю replace. `out_str = doc
new_str = str(out_str).replace(';', '')
doc = new_str`

Answer (score 0):

`el[i]` бессмысленно, хватит просто `el`. Тогда `enumerate()` бесполезно, `str()` тоже, и код будет выглядеть просто так:

```
for el in doc:
    el = el.replace(',', '').replace(';', '')
    csvwriter.writerow(doc)
```